# SocketTimeoutException indicated as unreachable

Tags: java

Following is a small section of a java application I am attempting to write:

```
Socket socket = new Socket(hostname, portnumber);
DataInputStream socketInput = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
try{
    socket.setSoTimeout(10000);
    try{
        byte[] msgHeader = new byte[4];
        if (socketInput.read(msgHeader) != -1)
        {
            // process message
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        // process exception
    }
    catch (SocketTimeoutException ste)
    {
        // process exception
    }
}
catch (SocketException se)
{
    // process exception
}
```

I am getting an error that states the catch(SocketTimeoutException) is not reachable.  I want to establish a socket timeout to prevent the socket read() from blocking forever, and if the SocketTimeoutException occurs my application will attempt to establish a socket connection to the next server available and attempt the same read() operation.

Any help provided is greatly appreciated since I have tried using different IO classes to no success.

Answer (score 1):

Since `SocketTimeoutException` is a subclass of `IOException` control will never reach the catch block which is catching `SocketTimeoutException`. Exception will be always caught by IOException catch block
Change the position of those catch blocks :

```
 catch (SocketTimeoutException e)
    {
        // process exception
    }
    catch (IOException ste)
    {
        // process exception
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for you quick reply/response.  I realized my issue prior to reviewing your reply/response and removing my question. However, I do greatly appreciate your response.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/SocketTimeoutException.html): SocketTimeoutException extends IOException. So, if one is thrown in the try block, it will be caught by the first catch block, and will thus never reach the second one.

Inverse the order of the two catch blocks, and everything should be fine.